# Angular.js - refresh view ng-options after modify data

Tags: angularjs, ajax, refresh, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I have select with ng-options, it uses data from one of controllers. Data is two-dimension array retrieved by ajax on app start with key-value pairs like:

```
'option1' : array[ 1: "Test", 2: "Test2" ],
'option2' : array[ 12: "abc", 26: "zyc" ],
'option3' : array[ 14: "fdfd", 27: "fdf" ],
'option4' : array[ 15: "dff", 28: "dffd" ],
```

and view:

```
<select name="selectedLink" id="selectedLink" ng-model="selectedLink" ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in links[selectedType]" ng-change="changeLinkName()" placeholder="Please Select" class="annotation-element">
```

Everything works fine in app start, but there is problem after modify my links array. User can add new element and it looks like:

```
// Watch new element variables
$scope.addNewElement = function() {
    var newElement = $('#inputElementId').val();
    // (...)
    $scope.links[newElement[0]][newElement[1]] = newElement[2];
    $scope.selectedLink = newElement[1];
    // (...)
};
```

The problem is that view doesn't refresh. There is still only old links array data in select options. I tried use $scope.$apply, but it doesn't work.

I can only "redraw" all options using jquery, but then I can't use ng-model, ng-change etc. What should I do to trigger refresh UI after change array data?

Comment: Please post a fiddle if possible. What i'm also seeing is that you are using `var newElement = $('#inputElementId').val();` - I don't see why you are not using the `directive`or ``binding` approach - the main advantage of Angular.

Comment: I use hidden field because of data "transmission". My app run in iframe, and field is set by parent function after other iframe interaction - page with form loading by fancybox, after save data goes through main window to angular app iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example. If you call your "add" function from a '[ng-click]` it should update.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('someCtrl', function ( $scope ) {
    $scope.opts = [
      {id: '1', name: 'Option 1'},
      {id: '2', name: 'Option 2'},
      {id: '3', name: 'Option 3'}
    ];
    $scope.model = $scope.opts[0];
  
    $scope.add = function () {
      var idx = $scope.opts.length + 1;
      $scope.opts.push({ id: idx, name: 'Option ' + idx });
    };
  });

angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    angular.bootstrap(document.querySelector('#app'), ['app']);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div id="app" ng-controller="someCtrl">
  <button type="button" ng-click="add()">Add</button>
  <hr>
  <select ng-model="model" ng-options="o.name for o in opts"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: I test several options and with new select nad simple array + button with ng-click it works fine - in both cases (user interaction and click by trigger()). Unfortunately, on main array it doesn't work.

I move data from two-dimensional array to variable (after each update) and... still nothing.

Comment: Could you maybe create a code example? With your exact (ng-)options?